# Using absolute dragMode in grapesjs

Tags: angular, typescript, grapesjs

In my angular app I'm trying to use the absolute `dragMode` like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5nmf6w?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

So in my component.ts I added dragMode:

```
  grapesjs.init({
  container: '#gjs',
  autorender: true,
  forceClass: false,
  dragMode: 'absolute',
  components: '',
  style: '',
```

it's giving an error saying editor isn't defined while dragging a block, how can I fix this and also how can I make specific blocks have absolute `dragMode`.

Answer (score 1):

Hack: if editor is available globally then it works. Like assign editor to window.editor. I faced the same issue. So far there is no explanation why editor is undefined while in absolute mode.

```
window.editor = this.editor;
```

I'm not sure if it is a best way.

component.set('dmode', 'absolute');
OR

```
editor.on("component:selected", function (model) {
  if (component.attributes.type === 'Your component type') {
    model.set('dmode', 'absolute');
 }
});
```

Comment: this was fixed in the newer version. See their github page.